как собрать ios приложение в kotlin multiplatform через Android Studio?
Подскажите пожалуйста как собрать ios приложение в kotlin multiplatform через Android Studio и возможно ли это вообще?

Как собрать приложение для iOS. В ВAndroid Studio. iOS. Android Studio. Загадка от Жака Фреско: "сколько?" (Извиняюсь за избыточный сарказм.)

Никак не собрать: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/kotlin-multiplatform-dev/multiplatform-integrate-in-existing-app.html#make-your-cross-platform-application-work-on-ios

Извините за тупость

Мне кажется, Android Studio само за себя говорит - Android, а для ios, вроде, нужен xcode.
Извините, если ошибаюсь.
